# HttpContext.Current.Session giving a StackOverflowException?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0

I am getting a StackOverflowException on the highlighted line of code in the snippet below which is in Global.asax.cs, can someone please tell me why this could be happening?

Code:

```
public static HttpSessionState CurrentSession
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current == null)
                    return null;
                return HttpContext.Current.Session;
            }
        }
```

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Its not giving me the stack trace, seems to be occurring in external code or another thread or something.

Comment: Are you sure the code that calls your property is not constantly pulling its value until it is *not* null?

Comment: Place a breakpoint in there on this line 'return HttpContext.Current.Session;' and see if Session has a value.

Comment: Your stack overflow is not happening here.  Maybe post the code that calls this --- the code that is involved in the stack overflow (since you are probably calling this from a couple of places).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was infact:
"Your stack overflow is not happening here. Maybe post the code that calls this --- the code that is involved in the stack overflow (since you are probably calling this from a couple of places). – Eben Roux Jun 30 at 4:37"

It was occurring in the code that requests CurrentSession, but that is just the line it was breaking on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the exact line highlighted in the code sample.  It "feels" like endless recursion.  I don't know how that would happen, unless somehow session was returning session and on and on.  Probably not the problem, but it's a thought.